# How to find the source branch for a tag

Tags: svn

I have a tag in subversion that has been made some time in the past. I would like to know what branch it was created from. Is there a way to do this. I have tried

```
svn log --stop-on-copy
```

But this only gives me the revision number, not the branch path. I need the branch path so I can check it out. Any ideas, preferably a SVN command line method here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 23):

`svn log -v --stop-on-copy <url-of-the-tag>` should give you this information as [documented here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html).

Relevant excerpt:

```
In addition to the action codes which precede the changed paths, svn log with the
--verbose (-v) option will note whether a path was added or replaced as the result of 
a copy operation. It does so by printing (from COPY-FROM-PATH:COPY-FROM-REV) after such 
paths.
```

Comment: But it gives me below message **svn: OPTIONS of 'tag url': 200 OK (server root url)**

Answer (score 11):

To get directly the right revision:

```
svn log -v -r0:HEAD --stop-on-copy --limit 1 <url-of-the-tag>
```

It will only print the revision from which a branch is created:

```
rxxx | Author | 2013-01-25 11:43:55 +0100 (fri., 2013, jan. 25) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /project/branches/branch (from /project/trunk/folder:ryyy)
```

The revision and path you are looking are: `/project/trunk/folder:ryyy`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late, but I happened to stumble upon this while developing some PowerShell scripts

If you can use PowerShell, this may output the path which the tag/branch was copied from directly:

```
([Xml](svn log -v -r0:HEAD --stop-on-copy --limit 1 URL-HERE --xml)).log.logentry.paths.path.'copyfrom-path'
```

What happens here? The svn command is invoked with the --xml flag, so i can cast the returned value to [Xml], which in turn allows me to access the XML-Nodes of the svn-output.